# SQL server set identity max value

Tags: sql-server, identity

I want to create a column with identity property and I want to specify its max value.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1)
)
```

I want to specify 20000 as a max value for ID.

Comment: and what you assume to get after 20000?

Comment: @voo: same thing that happens when it usually reaches max value -> get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alter table tbl add constraint CHK_TBL_MAX_ID check (id <= 2000)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa60c/1/1)

Comment: This is okay; just a minor difference is that after identity reaches it's usual max it fails with `arithmetic overflow`, and this will fail with `check constraint`. Not a big thing but if you are going to catch such exceptions, it could be useful.