# Setting max limit for Identity columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to know if we can set a maximum limit for an identity column? Like in DB2, we can achieve this by using `MAX` clause of identity column.

Something like :

```
create table test
(
    id int generated always as identity(start with 1, increment by 1, max 100),         
    name varchar(50)
)
```

Same way can we set maximum limit explicitly for identity column in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652741/sql-server-set-identity-max-value

Answer (score 1):

he limit is related to the datatype itself, not with the fact of being auto increment. You cannot change it.

But, of course you can do some work around...

Like:

An INT will take you up to 2,147,483,647.

So you can start after:

```
CREATE TABLE [MYTABLE]
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY(600000,1),
     .....
)
```

Or of course, you can create a constraint

Comment: Nope!.You can do that by setting a check constraint on the identity column

Comment: It isn't the something. He didn't ask for an check, but only for a natural way to do.

Comment: He is asking for a suggestion can we set maximum limit explicitly for identity column in sql server? there is a way to do that so we cannot say that it is not possible!!

Comment: He asked also if there are someway like he was used to do in DB2. Something without constraints.